# Injective function $f: A \rightarrow B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that $|B| \geq |A|$. Given that $B$ is $[0,1]$ (the real interval) and $A$ is $\mathbb P$ (the set of all primes).

I know I need to define an injective function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and I need to use the injection rule to make my proof.

I need help after this though. What should $f$ be and how should I go from there, especially considering $A$ and $B$ have infinite cardinalities.

Comment: Why not just map a prime $p$ to $\frac1p$?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: you must find an injective function (i.e., which satisfies that, if $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$, then $x_{1}=x_{2}$, the "injection rule" you mention, better known simply as injectivity of the function) of the form $f:\mathbb{P}\rightarrow[0,1]$.

As Brian M. Scott points out in a comment, the map $f:\mathbb{P}\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f(p)=1/p$ is a very natural choice:

- the function is well-defined, since for any prime number $p\in\{2, 3, 5, 7, ...\}$, $1/p$ is a real number (strictly) between $0$ and $1$;
- the function is injective: take prime numbers $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ and assume $f(p_{1})=f(p_{2})$; then
  $$\frac{1}{p_{1}}=\frac{1}{p_{2}};$$
  by multiplying both sides by $p_{1}p_{2}$ (what you can do since $p_{1}p_{2}$ is not zero, given both $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are prime numbers), you get $p_{2}=p_{1}$, what means $f$ is injective,

and there you go, you presented an injective function, although both sets are infinite.

Other possible functions satisfying what you want are:

- $f$ taking a prime number $p$ to $1/\alpha^{p}$, for a fixed real number $\alpha>1$;
- if $p$ is the $n$-th prime number, $f$ taking $p$ to $1/n$;
- if $p$ is the $n$-th prime number, $f$ taking $p$ to $1/\alpha^{n}$, for a fixed real number $\alpha>0$;
- if $p$ is written, in decimal notation, as $a_{1}\cdots a_{n}$, for digits $a_{1}$ through $a_{n}$, $f$ taking $p$ to $0.a_{1}\cdots a_{n}$;
- etc...